# How to add a unique number to each dropdown tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list where each item is closed until you click that particular item.

HTML:

```
<div id="dropdowntabs">
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a id="tabhead1" href="javascript:dropdowntabs('droptab1');">MAIN TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div name="droptab" class="droptab" id="droptab1" style="display:none;">
    <p>TEXT TO SHOW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function dropdowntabs(selectedtab) {
   $('div[name|="droptab"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == selectedtab) {
         $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
         $(this).hide(600);
      }
   });
}
```

Each droptab has a different number assigned to it. This works fine in HTML but I wanted to use it in Wordpress and as I can't manually assign a number to each tab they are all opening when one is clicked.

Could anybody explain how I can get the number to be added in increments automatically please.

Much appreciated,
Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic traverses instead. Within an event handler `this` is the element that event occurs on and starting at that element you can traverse to the corresponding matching element

```js
$('.drop a').click(function() {
  var $content = $(this).parent().next().show(200)
  $('.droptab').not($content).hide(200);
});
```

```css
.droptab {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowntabs">
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>MAIN TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>MAIN TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>SECOND TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>SECOND TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had almost all the code already there: look at the example:

In this example we don't need `id`s anymore, we use the respective indices to select and show.

```js
//select on index not on ID

function dropdowntabs(selectedtab) {
  //select the index number comparing the clicked element to it's nodelist
  $('div.droptab').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).index('div.droptab') == selectedtab) {
      $(this).show(200);
    } else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  });
}

//Assign the click events
$('h2.drop > a').on("click", function(e) {
  //select the index number comparing the clicked element to it's nodelist
  dropdowntabs($(this).index("h2 > a"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowntabs">
  <a></a>
  <!-- assign click handlers through code -->
  <h2 class="drop"><a id="tabhead1" href="javascript:void(0);">MAIN TITLE</a> <a id="tabhead2" href="javascript:void(0);">MAIN TITLE 2</a></h2>
  <div name="droptab" class="droptab" style="display:none;">
    <p>TEXT TO SHOW</p>
  </div>
  <div name="droptab" class="droptab" style="display:none;">
    <p>TEXT TO SHOW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```